# MATLAB: Given A and B, where size(B,1)<size(A,1), return I such that A(I,:) = B

Tags: matlab, find, indices

This is my code but I'm sure MATLAB provides a more elegant way to do this. Any thoughts?

```
all = csvread('TRAINING_i.csv');
actual = csvread('TRAINING_INPUTS.csv');
indTraining = zeros(size(actual,1),1);

for i = 1:size(actual,1)

    indTraining(i,1) = find(ismember(all, actual(i,:), 'rows'));

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I follow exactly but I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
A = [1 2; 
     3 4; 
     5 6; 
     7 8];

B = [3 4; 
     7 8];

for i = 1:size(B,1)

    indTraining(i,1) = find(ismember(A, B(i,:), 'rows'));

end
```

indTraining now is `[2, 4]`. This is more easily achieved as follows:

```
[~, indTraining] = ismember(B, A, 'rows')
```

No loops needed nor `find`. If you find yourself using `find` on a common function in Matlab, it's worth checking the docs on that function first because the second or third output to many common functions is often the indexes of what ever the function did and will save you the trouble e.g. second output of `max` etc

Lastly don't use `all` as a variable name in matlab because you're masking [a very useful function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html).

Comment: Note I have `ismember(B,A...` not `ismember(A,B...` you need to flip your inputs. Also you won't get the `0` that way.

Comment: Yes my bad. I will delete the comments